# Error about `relative_url_root=`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Testing the project in localhost works great, but after generate the .war and publish on server the error was returned is:

```
(ArgumentError) wrong number of arguments calling `relative_url_root=` (1 for 0)
```

I tried search some solutions about and I dont find anything, I am beginner with Ruby on Rails, if someone needs more information just ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using this one: [ActionController::AbstractRequest.relative_url_root=](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/AbstractRequest/relative_url_root=/class%).
The method is deprecated since Rails 3.0.

Are you using different Rails versions?

Use scope or namespace in config/routes.rb instead. Please have a look at [Rails Guides about Controller Namespaces and Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) or provide more information about what you're trying to accomlish.

Comment: I'm using rails 3.0.10, the strange is that in my localhost all works great. You know how can I check my two environments to find the difference of configuration?